# how to get the volume name (label) by using a local url?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have looked at NSWorkSpace and NSFileManager but I can't find out the methods that I'm looking for.

I have a saved url (getting from NSSavePanel).

ie. this url can be /Users/Josh/Some Folders/file.txt or
/Volumes/My USB Key Name/file.txt

So can I use this url to find out the displayed volume name?

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedLocalVolumePaths]` can list all the local volume name, but it's Deprecated in os x 10.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer:

```
NSURL *savedPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[saveURL.path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
NSError *error;
NSString *volumeName;

[savedPath getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
NSLog(@"volume name: %@ url: %@", volumeName, savedPath);
```

Comment: Note that the reason the author has used `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` is because in his example case, no file exists at `saveURL`. Calling getResourceValue: on a URL that does not exist will result in `NSCocoaErrorDomain` / `NSFileNoSuchFileError`.