# Returning the Volume Name of a Folder or a Volume

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, url

I need to get the volume name of any folder that the user selects.  In reference to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042941/how-to-get-the-volume-name-label-by-using-a-local-url/16043656#16043656), I've created the following function.

```
- (NSString *)getVolumeName:(NSString *)path {
    // path is the path of a folder
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *volumeName;
    [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
    return volumeName;
}
```

It works in most cases.  If the user selects a mounted volume, it can fail, though.  For example, I have an SDHC card inserted into the card slot of an iMac.  If I select this volume instead of a folder inside of it, the function above can return the name of the hard disk drive.  What is an infallible manner of returning the volume name of a folder or a volume?  Maybe use AppleScript?

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

Maybe something like the following?

```
- (NSString *)getVolumeName:(NSString *)path {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
    if ([[url path] isEqualTo:@"/Volumes"]) {
        return [path lastPathComponent];
    } else {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *volumeName;
        [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
        return volumeName; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think one stage (removing the last path component) is the culprit, and if you stopped doing that - it all will work fine. NSURL can give you the "volume name" resource from a full file/folder's path, and you don't need to pre-process or truncate it first. but if user selects a volume and you go on and truncate - you just lose the thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot test this at the moment, but I think you should work directly on the
given path, and not remove the last path component:

```
- (NSString *)getVolumeName:(NSString *)path {
    // path is the path of a folder
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *volumeName;
    [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
    return volumeName;
}
```

Comment: I guess nobody has an objection.  So I've marked it as a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: For posterity: See the comment I've posted in the referenced topic in the original post explaining why the last path component is chopped off.

And an important note: Calling getResourceValue: on a URL that does not exist will result in NSCocoaErrorDomain / NSFileNoSuchFileError

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use

```
-(NSString *)volumeNameForPath:(NSString *)path
{       
    NSArray* components = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] componentsToDisplayForPath:path];
    NSString* volumeName = components.first ?: "Unknown";       
    return volumeName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
FileManager.default.componentsToDisplay(forPath: url.path)?.first
```

or:

```
extension URL {

    func volumeName() -> String? {
        guard let resourceValues = try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeNameKey]) else {
            return nil
        }

        return resourceValues.volumeName
    }

}
```